# SMTP relay with FQDN, but SpamAssassin marks FSL_HELO_NON_FQDN_1 and HELO_NO_DOMAIN

Tags: postfix, smtp, spamassassin

my mail provider (posteo.de) offers an FQDN during the HELO/EHLO exchange (e.g. mout2.posteo.de) – which is seen by policyd-spf (s. below) – but SpamAssassin on a receiving server marks the relay as offering no FQDN or domain:

```
Feb  2 06:17:10 eden policyd-spf[478301]: prepend Received-SPF: Pass (mailfrom) identity=mailfrom; client-ip=185.67.36.66; helo=mout02.posteo.de; envelope-from=xxx@posteo.de; receiver=<UNKNOWN> 
Feb  2 06:17:10 eden postfix/smtpd[478286]: 502C97F91B: client=mout02.posteo.de[185.67.36.66]
Feb  2 06:17:10 eden postfix/cleanup[478303]: 502C97F91B: message-id=<xxx@xxx.xxx>
Feb  2 06:17:10 eden spamd[423260]: spamd: connection from 127.0.0.1 [127.0.0.1]:60310 to port 783, fd 6
Feb  2 06:17:10 eden spamd[423260]: spamd: processing message <xxxxx> for xxx:111
Feb  2 06:17:13 eden spamd[423260]: spamd: clean message (0.8/6.0) for xxx:111 in 3.6 seconds, 1910 bytes.
Feb  2 06:17:13 eden spamd[423260]: spamd: result: . 0 - DKIM_SIGNED,DKIM_VALID,DKIM_VALID_AU,DKIM_VALID_EF,FSL_HELO_NON_FQDN_1,HELO_NO_DOMAIN,SPF_PASS,UNPARSEABLE_RELAY,URIBL_BLOCKED scantime=3.6,size=1910,required_score=6.0,rhost=127.0.0.1,raddr=127.0.0.1,autolearn=no autolearn_force=no
```

Why doesn't SpamAssassin see the FQDN which is obviously present?

Thanks,
Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SpamAssassin looks into `Received:` headers of the message, not into the SMTP session with your mail provider. The message can pass multiple mail relays before going through your mail provider and any of the corresponding `Received:` header can indicate missing HELO (bare IP in square brackets).

Comment: Thanks! I checked the Received headers, but they do contain complete entries like `mout01.posteo.de (mout01.posteo.de [185.67.36.65])` for all mail relays. (BTW, my own (intermediate) mail server is listed as `my.mail.server (unknown [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX])` – what configuration parameter causes the 'unknown' string?

Comment: I realized a missing PTR record is responsible for "unknown".